# UICollectionView's contentOffset changed on reload

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm working **`UICollectionView`** and facing issue with `contentOffset` while reloading the data.

I already read multiple posts regarding this, but couldn't find any solution.

**Issue:**

`UINavigationController` -> **`ViewController1`** (`rootViewController`)

`ViewController1` contains a `vertical` `UICollectionView` that contains multiple `UICollectionViewCells`.

On tapping a particular `UICollectionViewCell`, **`ViewController2`** is pushed into the `navigation stack`.

Now, on returning back to **`ViewController1`**, I'm `reloading` the `UICollectionView` which changes the previous `contentOffset`.

**What is required?**

I don't want the `contentOffset` of `UICollectionView` to be changed when I return back to **`ViewController1`** from **`ViewController2`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code for reloading your collectionView:

```
let contentOffset = collectionView.contentOffset
    collectionView.reloadData()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
    collectionView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)
```

Comment: It's not working. `contentOffset` is always (x: 0, y: 0).

Comment: you should call this before you reloading.
because i have written code for reloading in it.

Comment: Ok. I did that. But still not working. I am getting the `contentOffset` but `collectionView.setContentOffset(contentOffset, animated: false)` doesn't do anything.

Comment: `collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` did the trick for me. Setting content offset just after `reloadData()` does not work always, because I think there is a race condition between reloading and setting offset.